# Google Plus or Facebook Style Image Popup Viewer?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Looking for an AJAX image viewer that goes full screen like G+ or FB, where you can use arrow keys, and it goes full screen, work on all browsers if possible :)

Anything out there? Been googling for days now, only to come across stuff like Lightbox.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can't seriously be telling me you found nothing.. http://webdesignzo.com/jquery-lightbox-scripts-mootools-prototype/ first search. and I searched for your exact question title on google. Are you trolling? It is a lightbox.. that is what it is called. People (like facebook or G+) put their own spin on it.

Comment: and before someone spins up the response that LightBox is a specific application and the rest are clones... I realize that. But it's like calling all tissues Klenex.. It just happened.

Comment: Don't be rude rlemon, you sound kind of sour! +1 from me Andrew I was trying to get to the bottom of this too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used [ColorBox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) in many of my projects. It is pretty customizable and well-documented.

Answer (score 1):

try http://lytebox.com/

Answer (score 0):

A good gallery image viewer on popup would be [Blueimp Gallery](https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/), which is **responsive** along with the ability to play videos. It is well documented as well.

However, if you are looking for an image viewer along with a customizable div section, say for comments, [JQuery FB Photo Box](http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Creating-A-Image-Viewer-with-Descriptions-Like-Facebook-jQuery-FBPhotoBox.html) Lightbox plugin is useful.